# How to separate price value and sale price value from this function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this function for display the product prices, and getting this output:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'add_design_price_html', 100, 2 );
function add_design_price_html( $price, $product ){
    if(is_single() && $price != "")

       $actual_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );

     return $actual_price;
}
```

this function rendering this output in html:

```
<p class="price"><del><span class="amount">$99.00</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">$78.00</span></ins></p>
```

So how could I get these price values separately in php variables.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Use session variables and get it from them.

Comment: what does it make difference????, I am just asking to separate these two price value from the output html and get in two different variables... :)

Comment: Those two price values comes from only php variable, right?